# getting all attributes for nested relationships in laravel in one JSON

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get all attributes in one JSON.

Eg:
Consider I have a table "place" with "id","name","description" as attributes.
Now,
I have another table "region" with "id","name","place_id","description" as attributes(or) schema.
There is one to many relationship between place and region.

And now,I define another table "street" with "id","name","region_id" as its schema.
There is again One to Many relationship between "region" and "street".

I want to get all details which comes in one place.If there is some place "1,banglore,garden city" and there are two regions with that place_id as
"{"1,r.t.nagar,1,region in banglore"},{"2,ashok nagar,1,region in banglore"}".Here "1" is foreign key referring id of "banglore's id(1)".

Now,similarly if each region has 3 streets in street table.I want to get all the values in one JSON. I know that we can get this with **foreach** .But,i want an efficient solution to get all nested relationship to my Place model from Region,Street in JSON.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define one to many relations like:

```
 class Places extends Eloquent{
 ....
    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Region');
    }
 ...
 }
```

And the same to streets:

```
 class Regions extends Eloquent{
 ....
 public function streets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Street');
    }
....
}
```

Note that I have assumed that your models stay within App folder and have corresponding namespaces. 
After that you can get you model like:

```
Place::with('regions.streets')->get();
```

Which will automatically nest all relations and cast to JSON if you send a json response.

Comment: Place::with('regions.streets')->find($id); will get all the relations associated with that id.